# how to format my txt file output into excel in wincmd or powershell

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd

I have these a .txt with the below output and need this in a excel with column name as "Name, ID, Location, Role" and repective details below in their rows.

```
Name: Murali
ID: 485
location: Trichy
Role: AS
Name: John
ID: 584
location: NY
Role: AS
Name: Oisce
ID: 358
location: NBC
Role: AS
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We are a community to help programmers and programming enthusiasts. That being said, it is expect that you show what you have done or tried before posting. This gives us something to build on. As of now this reads like a code writing request which is off topic for SO. Break your question into its parts and search individually for solutions to those problems. Then, if you are still having issues, please [edit] your question showing your work so we can better help you and the community.

Comment: Also, please [format your code and sample input and output properly](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/248777). Originally, due to lack of formatting, your multi-line input appeared to consist of just a single line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a pure [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) solution; provide the text file to reformat as a command line argument:

```bat
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_FILES=%~1"

for /F "delims== eol==" %%E in ('2^> nul set $') do set "%%E="

for %%F in ("%_FILES%") do (
    if /I "%%~xF"==".csv" (set "EXT=_NEW.csv") else set "EXT=.csv"
    set "FLAG=#"
    < "%%~F" set /P LONE=""
    set "FILE=%%~F"
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    > "%%~dpnF!EXT!" (
        for /F "tokens=1,* delims=: eol=:" %%K in ('type "!FILE!" ^& echo^(!LONE!') do (
            endlocal
            set "HEAD=%%K"
            set "DATA=%%L"
            if defined FLAG set "FLAG=,"
            set "LINE=,"
            setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
            if defined $!HEAD! (
                for /F "tokens=1,* delims== eol==" %%G in ('set $') do (
                    endlocal
                    set "NAME=%%G"
                    set "ITEM=%%H"
                    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
                    for /F "tokens=1,* delims=: eol=:" %%E in ("!FLAG!"!NAME:*$^=!",:!LINE!"!ITEM!",") do (
                        endlocal
                        if defined FLAG set "FLAG=%%E"
                        set "LINE=%%F"
                        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
                    )
                )
                if defined FLAG (
                    echo(!FLAG:~1,-1!
                    echo(!LINE:~1,-1!
                    endlocal
                    set "FLAG="
                ) else (
                    echo(!LINE:~1,-1!
                    endlocal
                )
                for /F "delims== eol==" %%E in ('set $') do set "%%E="
                setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
            )
            if "!DATA:~,1!"==" " set "DATA=!DATA:~1!"
            for /F "delims=" %%E in ("$!HEAD!=!DATA!") do (
                endlocal
                set "%%E"
                setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
            )
        )
    )
    endlocal
)

endlocal
exit /B
```

The output CSV file using your input file would look like:

> ```bat
> "ID","location","Name","Role"
> "485","Trichy","Murali","AS"
> "584","NY","John","AS"
> "358","NBC","Oisce","AS"
> ```

---

#### Update

Here is an improved version of the script that preserves the original order of fields as they first appear in the input file:

```bat
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_FILES=%~1"
set "_RSLTS=%~2"

rem // Clear all dynamic variables:
for /F "delims==" %%E in ('2^> nul set #') do set "%%E="
for /F "delims==" %%E in ('2^> nul set $') do set "%%E="

rem // Loop through the given file(s) to resolve its/their path(s):
for %%F in ("%_FILES%") do (
    if /I "%%~xF"==".csv" (set "FEXT=_NEW.csv") else set "FEXT=.csv"
    set "FLAG=#"
    < "%%~F" set /P LONE=""
    set "FILE=%%~F"
    set "RSLT=%%~dpnF"
    set /A "IDX=0"
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    if defined _RSLTS (set "RSLT=con") else set "RSLT=!RSLT!!FEXT!"
    rem // Write to output file all at once:
    > "!RSLT!" (
        rem /* Read input file line by line, repeat first line once again finally, because
        rem    this contains an already present header for sure and therefore initiates
        rem    returning the previously collected last output data row: */
        for /F "tokens=1,* delims=: eol=:" %%K in ('type "!FILE!" ^& echo^(!LONE!') do (
            endlocal
            set "HEAD=%%K"
            set "DATA=%%L"
            if defined FLAG set "FLAG=,"
            set "LINE=,"
            set /A "IDX+=1"
            setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
            rem /* Check if current header is already present; if so, begin collecting a
            rem    new data row and return the previously collected one: */
            if defined $!HEAD! (
                rem // Read dynamic variable corresponding to current header indirectly:
                for /F "tokens=1,* delims==" %%G in ('set #') do (
                    for /F "tokens=1,* delims=:" %%E in ("!FLAG!"%%H",:!LINE!"!$%%H!",") do (
                        endlocal
                        if defined FLAG set "FLAG=%%E"
                        set "LINE=%%F"
                        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
                    )
                )
                rem /* Return the currently collected data row, together with the column
                rem    header row in case it is the first time: */
                if defined FLAG (
                    echo(!FLAG:~1,-1!
                    echo(!LINE:~1,-1!
                    endlocal
                    set "FLAG="
                ) else (
                    echo(!LINE:~1,-1!
                    endlocal
                )
                rem // Clear all dynamic variables:
                for /F "delims==" %%E in ('set #') do set "%%E="
                for /F "delims==" %%E in ('set $') do set "%%E="
                set /A "IDX=1"
                setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
            )
            rem // Remove leading white-spaces from data value:
            for /F "tokens=* eol= " %%E in ("!DATA!") do (
                endlocal
                set "DATA=%%E"
                setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
            )
            rem /* Assign name of dynamic variable corresponding with current header to a
            rem    numeric dynamic variable for preserving the order of (first) headers: */
            set "IDX=000!IDX!"
            for /F "delims=" %%E in ("#!IDX:~-4!=!HEAD!") do (
                endlocal
                set "%%E"
                setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
            )
            rem // Assign data value to dynamic variable corresponding with current header:
            for /F "delims=" %%E in ("$!HEAD!=!DATA!") do (
                endlocal
                set "%%E"
                setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
            )
        )
    )
    endlocal
)

endlocal
exit /B
```

The output CSV file using your input file would look like:

> ```bat
> "Name","ID","location","Role"
> "Murali","485","Trichy","AS"
> "John","584","NY","AS"
> "Oisce","358","NBC","AS"
> ```

Answer (score 3):

The following is a **generic PowerShell v3+ solution** that works with any field names of any number (assuming that the lines repeat with the same field names, in the same order); it **transforms the input directly into a CSV file** that can be opened in Excel:

```
# Determine input and output file.
$inFile = 'file.txt'
$outFile = 'file.csv'

# Extract the headers from the input file, using an ordered hashtable.
# Lines are read, and each line's 1st field is added as a key to the hashtable
# until a duplicate value is found in the 1st field.
$headers = [ordered] @{}
foreach($line in (Get-Content $inFile)) {
  $colName = ($line -split ': ', 2)[0]
  if ($headers.Contains($colName)) { break }
  $headers.$colName = $null
}

# Construct the header row and send it to the output file.
# Choose a suitable character encoding.
"`"$($headers.Keys -join '","')`"" | Out-File -Encoding Utf8 $outFile

#`# Now loop over all lines and write the data rows.
$numCols = $headers.Count
$outLine = ''
$sep = ''
$i = 0
foreach($line in (Get-Content $inFile)) {
  ++$i # Count lines starting at 1.
  $val = ($line -split ': ', 2)[1]
  # Enclose the value in "...", if necessary.
  if ($val -match '[ ,"]') { $val = "`"$($val -replace '"', '\"')`"" }
  #`# Add to the output line at hand.
  $outLine += $sep + $val
  if ($i % $numCols -eq 0) { # Last column value.
    # Complete output line assembled, append it to the file.
    # Note that the -Encoding value must match the one above.
    $outLine | Add-Content -Encoding Utf8 $outFile
    $sep = ''
    $outLine = ''
  } else { # 1st or interior column value
    $sep = ','
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without a need to format this in Excel is simply done by separating your fields with a character like , or ; (depending on your language settings in Excel) and renaming the file to have the externsion .csv, eg "data.csv".

When you open the file from explorer Excel will open this file and arrange your data in columns and rows. You could format the layout in Excel and save it as a XLSX file.

Here your data formatted as CSV with , as separator

```
Name, id, location, role
Murali, 485, Trichy, AS
John, 584, NY, AS
Oisce, 358, NBC, AS
```

EDIT: because of the challenge of mklement0 here a one line Ruby solution, NOT PART OF THE ANSWER, I'm sure not the shortest or best solution, just a proof of concept

```
%(
Name: Murali
ID: 485
location: Trichy
Role: AS
Name: John
ID: 584
location: NY
Role: AS
Name: Oisce
ID: 358
location: NBC
Role: AS
).scan(/(^\w+):( \w+)/).transpose.each_with_index.map{|r,i|i==0 ? r.uniq.collect{|x| %("#{x.strip}") }.join(',') : r.each_slice(4).map{|s|s.collect{|x| %("#{x.strip}") }.join(',')}}.join("\n")
```

here split up by operation with explanation

```
s.scan(/(^\w+):( \w+)/) # array of arrays (key, value), based on regular expression
 .transpose.each_with_index.map{|r,i| # transpose to array of headers and values, use Enumerator
   i==0 ? # first line = headers
   r.uniq.collect{|x| %("#{x}") }.join(',') # unique values, surround with "", join with ","
   : # rest of the lines = data
   r.each_slice(4).map{|s| # pieces of 4 items
     s.collect{|x| %("#{x.strip}") } # surround with ""
     .join(',')}} # join with ","
 .join("\n") # join with new line char
```

Or a shorter variant (s contains the string to parse)

```
(s.lines[0..3].join.scan(/(^\w+): (\w+)/).transpose.first + s.lines.join.scan(/(^\w+): (\w+)/).transpose.last).each_slice(4).map{|a| %("#{a.join('","')}")}
```

EDIT2:
Reading from a file is as simple as `Fire.read("data.txt").scan(..)` etc.

I can read files in memory GB's big if necessary but yes Ruby has the lazy method which reads only the part that is needed at the moment. 
You can also use eg `File.foreach('data.txt').first(10)` which stops at reading at the 10th line.
Didn't want to make it too complicated though.
See eg http://blog.honeybadger.io/using-lazy-enumerators-to-work-with-large-files-in-ruby/

Comment: My guess is that the OP wants the input transformed _for_ use in Excel; i.e., to transform it beforehand (e.g., to a CSV), so it can be _opened in_ Excel. In other words: you're describing the _result_ of the desired transformation, whereas the OP is probably looking for how to perform that transformation in an automated fashion.

Comment: @mklement0 The OP has changed his question, that was unclear at the moment I answered, knowing what you have to reach is half of the solution isn't it ?

Comment: Got it. I merely provided context  that may help future readers (with the benefit of hindsight; also, in case you're wondering: I didn't down-vote your answer).

Comment: I did wonder because I just upvoted yours because of the effort you put into it 8:) Too bad any scripting language was't good enough, this could be a one line Ruby script I also upvoted the OP, it's unfair how fast people downvote, we scary users away like that

Comment: Intriguing: Feel free to share that (with a disclaimer saying that a Ruby solution wasn't asked for).

Comment: Thanks for the up-vote. Re down-votes: Agreed; I got a down-vote too, and I suspect someone methodically down-voted _all_ answers, because - if I were to guess - they didn't like the fact that people posted answers at all, given the lack of effort put into the question (needless to say, I disagree with this approach).

Comment: @mklement0 did so, hope I don't get more downvotes because of it 8:)

Comment: ++ for the impressive Ruby solution; the only things worth noting are that you're hard-coding the number of columns (is there a way around that in the one-liner?) and that reading all input into memory at once is only suitable for smallish files.

Comment: I'm always motivated to show the power of Ruby, see EDIT2